# SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning for ament_python build in ROS2 Humble

Tags: ros2, ros-humble

I understand this is a known issue, and the last question on this seems to be from [almost a year ago](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24230/setuptoolsdeprecationwarning-in-ros2-humble).

Has there been any progress in fixing this issue? What is the path forward? Downgrading setuptools version doesn't seem like a good option as pointed out by one of the answers to the old question.

I'm not really bothered about the warning, but just wondering what is being done to address it.