# Warnings while trying to build the code in the workspace of crystal ros2

Tags: ros2

```
/home/gp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/easy_install.py:159: EasyInstallDeprecationWarning: easy_install command is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  EasyInstallDeprecationWarning,
/home/gp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/setuptools/command/install.py:37: SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning: setup.py install is deprecated. Use build and pip and other standards-based tools.
  setuptools.SetuptoolsDeprecationWarning,
/home/gp/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pkg_resources/__init__.py:119: PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning: 0.18ubuntu0.18.04.1 is an invalid version and will not be supported in a future release
  PkgResourcesDeprecationWarning,
```

Comment: I updated the setuptools and pip, i use python 3.6 as default and i still have the warning

Comment: Just a note that `crystal` has been out of support since December 2019.  You may find that things don't work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can suppress python warnings by setting the `PYTHONWARNINGS` environment variable. Note that this is a warning and not an error, so your packages should still compile.

In case you want to suppress the warning, you can take a look at this [previously asked question](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/questions/24230/setuptoolsdeprecationwarning-in-ros2-humble) on Robotics Stack Exchange. Although the post I mentioned targets Humble, it should work for Crystal as well.

Also, I will encourage you to take a tour of the [Help Center](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help). Formatting your error logs as code blocks make it easier for someone else to do a text-search on the log. This might come in handy later on when you will post longer error logs/compilation messages. :)